# To run object inside an array exists in php

Tags: php, xml, csv

I am passing this object to csv separated by commas, but I see that inside there is an array (categorias) and this leaves it blank, how can I go through the categories values ​​too?

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [codigo] => 1100040 [familia] => HOGAR[categorias] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [string] => Array ( [0] => HOGAR>COCINA>MENAJE PARA COCINAR>SARTENES [1] => BAZAR>HOGAR>COCINA>MENAJE PARA COCINAR>SARTENES ) )[novedad] => false [promocion] => false
```

My code:

```
$articulos='MyFile.xml';


if (file_exists($articulos)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($articulos);
    $f = fopen('art.csv', 'w');
    // array to hold the field names
    $headers = array(); 
    // loop through the first set of fields to get names
    foreach ($xml->ArticulosD->ArticuloD->children() as $field) {  

        // put the field name into array
        $headers[] = $field->getName(); 
    }
    // print headers to CSV
    fputcsv($f, $headers, ';', '"');

    foreach ($xml->ArticulosD->ArticuloD as $users) {

        fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($users), ';', '"');
    }
    fclose($f);
    //print_r($xml);
}
```

> My xml file

```html
<ArticulosD>
  <ArticuloD>
    <codigo>10202</codigo>
    <familia>VARIOS</familia>
    <ean>9788425351501</ean><talla>ST</talla>
    <categorias>
      <string>cat1</string>
      <string>cat2</string>
      <string>cat3</string>
    </categorias>
 </ArticuloD>
<ArticulosD>
```

Comment: Please show us the "raw" information from MyFile.xml, thanks.

Comment: Can you look at it please?